# SqlException ID couldn't bind

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am getting this error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code additional information :
>
> Multipart identifier "P.DataID" could not be bound
>   Multipart identifier "P.DataID" could not be bound
>   Multipart identifier "P.Model" could not be bound .

I am not exactly sure if the issue is in the table or SQL setting or my program i had been trying you change the ids name without any luck and I had tried to remove the id from the `string data`

BTW I had modified `Production.Product(Data.Hjuldata)` & `Production.ProductSubCategory(Data.Mærke)` tables from Adventure Works database

SQL statement:

```
string connStrings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sql"];
string Data = @"Select top 5
                    ps.Mærket AS SubCategoryName, P.DataID, P.Model 
                from Data.Hjuldata 
                inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.DataID = PS.MærkeID";
```

I have a table alias as P

[image]

Comment: There simply is no table in your SQL statement that uses the `P` table alias - you have `Data.Hjuldata` without any alias, and `Data.Maerke` with an alias of `PS` .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `P` as an alias for `Data.Hjuldata`.

```
string Data = @"Select top 5
    ps.Mærket AS SubCategoryName, P.DataID, P.Model 
    from Data.Hjuldata P --<< added P
    inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.DataID = PS.MærkeID";
```